# How to solve this possion probability question (Involving Hypothesis Testing)

Tags: probability, statistics

My main question was;

if $X$~$Poisson(5)$ and say we have that
 $P(X > K)=0.068$, then how do I solve for K? Given that $\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$ and X is the sum of 20 iid.

But I have a few different things that I am confused and wondering about in this problem.

To give more context,

It is from a hypothesis testing problem which started off saying suppose $X_{1},...X_{n}$ are poisson random variables with mean $\lambda$ and we want to test null $\lambda=\lambda_{0}$ and alternative $\lambda=\lambda_{1}$.

It asked to find at level alpha the optimal test ie that which rejects the null when $\bar Xn \gt$ Constant. for this constant I said that for a given $K$ the optimal test will reject the null if $$\bar Xn \gt \frac{-lnK+n(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{0})}{nln(\lambda_{1}/\lambda_{o})}$$ and then it said, suppose $n=20$ the null is $1/4$ the alternate is $1/2$ , find that constant and type $1$ and $2$ probabilities

So I thought that this would mean $P(\bar Xn \gt C: \lambda=1/4)=0.068$ which
but that would be the same as $P(T \gt nc : \lambda=1/4)=0.068$ So If I can find that C and then divide by 20 to find my original constant and would it also be the type one probability.

The other part was the same except for the test which minimizes the sum of type one and two errors, for this one I found that it rejects the null when $$\bar Xn \gt \frac{ln(a/b)+n(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{0})}{nln(\lambda_{1}/\lambda_{o})}$$ and so I think I would take same approach. The thing is I don't get how this will be any different from above? I am so extremely confused. I cannot understand the difference between the two problems. I am begging anyone to please help

I have been working on this for over two days, so many hours. I am just so confused. I have tried all my work, but I cant put it together. Please help

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $T$ is the sum of 20 iid? 20 independently and identically distributed....what? Random variables? And where does $T$ come into play?

Comment: Sorry I meant X

Comment: How can we have Poisson(5) and $\lambda = \frac{1}{4}$. Shouldn't those be equal? I am also going to assume that you mean $X$ is the sum of 20 iid *random variables*.

Comment: X=X1+...+X20 where each of those X is iid and has $ \lambda=1/4$

Comment: Can you help please? I am so stuck

Comment: For solving the inequality, there is no "nice" way. It is best to add up $\Pr(X=0)$, $\Pr(X=1)$, and so on until the sum is about $0.932$.

Comment: Hi Andre, my teacher said we could use R to help, would that make it easier?

Comment: I pretty much give you the answer below. I will write it in R if you really need me to.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  I updated with all the work I could.Could you please provide some help? I am pulling my hair out ( not actually) here trying for hours on this

Comment: The original problem has been thoroughly solved  by Vladhagen.

Comment: I know I will accept and am very thankful, but it still leaves me with so many questions that I include in the updates

Comment: @AndréNicolas And my apologizes for updating with more but it took me very long time to type it up and I needed to be able to update as I went because I made mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDF for the Poisson distribution is $$\mathbb{P}(X \leq K) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j = 0}^{K}\dfrac{\lambda^j}{j!}.$$

I use $\lambda$ to refer to the Poisson parameter for the distribution of $X$ overall (i.e. $\lambda=5$ for my purposes here).

We know that $\mathbb{P}(X>K) = 0.068$.

Hence we can say that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq K) =1-0.068 = 0.932$.

Thus we need to solve $$\mathbb{P}(X \leq K)= e^{-5} \sum_{j = 0}^{K}\dfrac{5^j}{j!} = 0.932$$ for the value $K$.

We could get really fancy and work with error bounds on power series here, but I am going to give you a quick and dirty way to do this.

Start with $K = 4$ say.
$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq 4) = e^{-5}(1+5 + 25/2 + 125/6 + 625/24) = 0.4405.$$

This is too small. We want $0.932$. Maybe now try $K = 5$ or $K = 6$.

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq 5) = e^{-5}(1+5 + 25/2 + 125/6 + 625/24 + 5^5/120) = 0.616.$$

**Right around $K=8$ you might find something magical....**

This could be found by running the very simple command

`qpois(0.068, lambda = 5, lower.tail = FALSE)`

in R. However, that is going to return $9$, since we have some round off error. Instead try

`qpois(0.068095, lambda = 5, lower.tail = FALSE)`

Comment: I updated my question to try and show more work. Can I ask, does it seem okay? And then could I use same technique for the second part? Thank you a lot

Comment: From what I can tell it looks okay in part 1. There are details that are missing from your explanation in part 2 that I have not been able to pin down (example: what are $a$ and $b$ in part 2?).

Comment: a and b are such that the optimal test rejects the null when aL(null) <bL(alt) and accepts the null when aL(null) > bL(alt) where L is the likelyhood

Comment: Then your answers seem reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, but can I ask, then what is the different in the calculations of the last part if we don't even take into account the specific C?

Comment: And for example, if nc=8 then isn't what we want that P(T<=8:1/4)=0.068? but when I try in R; ppois(8,lambda=0.25,lower.tail=FALSE) I get something very diffirent

Comment: Maybe you use a different notation, but again, you need to make sure that the lambda you put into R matches the mean of the random variable you are looking at. The mean of $X$ is not $1/4$, it is $5$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still wondering, when do we account for the ln and stuff that I did in the first part?